# get refresh event from page

Tags: jquery

How to get event of page refresh. i want to detect that user has refreshed page

Answer (score 2):

not sure how to do it in Jquery

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var e = e || window.event;

  // For IE and Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Any string';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'Any string';
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Comment: This will catch refresh, back, forward, and closing of the window

Answer (score 2):

On $(document).load()

- read a var current_page from cookie
- if it's the same as your current page, you have a refresh
- write current page to var current_page in cookie

Comment: can u provide an example for the same

Answer (score 0):

The event you're looking for is beforeunload, you can stop a page refresh like this:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){ 
    return '';
});
```